# Force OpenSSH to prompt for user name

Tags: ssh

When you run ssh without a login_name argument, it automatically uses your local username as the login_name.  for example:

```
cogan@localhost$ ssh myserver
cogan@myserver's password:
```

Is there a way to force ssh to prompt for login_name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're talking about OpenSSH, the answer is no (you can check [the source](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/ssh.c?rev=HEAD&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup)). As pointed out by @cnicutar, you can use `ssh user@host` or configure aliases in `.ssh/config` along the lines of

```
Host meh
  HostName foo
  User bar
```

and then `ssh meh`.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.  I'm using ssh in a script, so I can just prompt the user for their name myself before making the call, I just wanted to see if there was a way I could have ssh save me the work.

Answer (score 4):

Since `ssh` does not have an option for forcing a username prompt; you can create the following script in your `~/bin` directory and name it `ssh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $user_at_address = $ARGV[0];
my @u_a = split(/@/, $user_at_address);

if (defined $u_a[1])
{
    if ( $^O == 'linux' )
    {
        exec ("/usr/bin/ssh $u_a[0]\@$u_a[1]");
    }
    if ( $^O == 'solaris' )
    {
        exec ("/usr/local/bin/ssh $u_a[0]\@$u_a[1]");
    }
}
else
{
    print "Enter your username: ";
    my $username = <STDIN>;
    chomp ( $username );
    if ( $^O == 'linux' )
    {
        exec ("/usr/bin/ssh $username\@$u_a[0]");
    }
    if ( $^O == 'solaris' )
    {
        exec ("/usr/local/bin/ssh $username\@$u_a[0]");
    }
}
```

Then, make the script executable:

```
chmod 755 ~/bin/ssh
```

Make sure you have `$HOME/bin` in your `PATH` (put `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` in your `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bashrc` and `source ~/.bashrc` or `source /etc/bashrc`).

Then, run it as you would `ssh`:

```
[ 12:49 jon@hozbox ~ ]$ ssh localhost
Enter your username: bob
bob@localhost's password:
[ 12:50 bob@hozbox /home/bob ]$
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an adaptation of @meh's answer.

In a shell script, we prompt the username.

We pass the username in a subsequent call to ssh.

The following runs `uptime` on `contosso.com`:

```sh
sshhost=contosso.com
read -p "$sshhost user [$USER]: " sshuser
[ "$sshuser" == "" ] && sshuser=$USER
ssh $sshuser@$sshhost uptime
```

Here's a sample output:

```sh
$ ./run-script.sh 
contosso.com user [stephen]: billgates
billgates@contosso.com password:
 10:57:12 up 71 days,  1:01,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.04, 0.05
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so -- if it were, it would be through .sshconfig

http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config

You could try setting User to something illegal to see what it does.

Comment: I just tried this for fun: `[ 12:56 Jonathan@MacBookPro ~ ]$ ssh /dev/null@somehost` actually works..: `/dev/null@somehost's password: ` -> `Permission denied, please try again.`.  Of course, in the hosts `/var/log/secure` it shows `sshd[21936]: pam_sepermit(sshd:auth): Cannot determine the user's name` and `sshd[21936]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): error retrieving information about user`.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Batch:

```
echo off
echo Please type your SSH username.
set /p usern
ssh -t %usern%@serveripaddress
```

Answer (score -1):

So I was having the same issue. I was using cmd

```
ssh "IP address"

ssh 000.000.000.0
```

And it was asking immediately for the password for a user that didn't exist (My computers Name).

really simple fix just use this command instead:

```
ssh root@"IP address"

ssh root@000.000.000.0
```

You can replace root with any username you want. This will cause the server to prompt you for the password to the username you desire.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. Besides the method you suggest has already been suggested in another answer four years ago.